# Neo4j OGM example with Scala

Tags: scala, neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I tried the example mentioned in Luanne's article [The essence of Spring Data Neo4j 4](https://www.airpair.com/neo4j/posts/the-essence-of-spring-data-neo4j-4) in Scala. The code can be found in the [neo4j-ogm-scala](https://github.com/mmwaikar/neo4j-ogm-scala) repository.

```
package neo4j.ogm.scala.domain

import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GraphId;
import scala.beans.BeanProperty
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory;

abstract class Entity {
  @GraphId
  @BeanProperty
  var id: Long = _

  override def equals(o: Any): Boolean = o match {
    case other: Entity => other.id.equals(this.id)
    case _ => false
  }

  override def hashCode: Int = id.hashCode()
}

@NodeEntity
class Category extends Entity {
  var name: String = _

  def this(name: String) {
    this()
    this.name = name
  }
}

@NodeEntity
class Ingredient extends Entity {
  var name: String = _

  @Relationship(`type` = "HAS_CATEGORY", direction = "OUTGOING")
  var category: Category = _

  @Relationship(`type` = "PAIRS_WITH", direction = "UNDIRECTED")
  var pairings: Set[Pairing] = Set()

  def addPairing(pairing: Pairing): Unit = {
    pairing.first.pairings +(pairing)
    pairing.second.pairings +(pairing)
  }

  def this(name: String, category: Category) {
    this()
    this.name = name
    this.category = category
  }
}

@RelationshipEntity(`type` = "PAIRS_WITH")
class Pairing extends Entity {
  @StartNode
  var first: Ingredient = _

  @EndNode
  var second: Ingredient = _

  def this(first: Ingredient, second: Ingredient) {
    this()
    this.first = first
    this.second = second
  }
}

object Neo4jSessionFactory {
  val sessionFactory = new SessionFactory("neo4j.ogm.scala.domain")

  def getNeo4jSession(): Session = {
    System.setProperty("username", "neo4j")
    System.setProperty("password", "neo4j")
    sessionFactory.openSession("http://localhost:7474")
  }
}

object Main extends App {
  val spices = new Category("Spices")
  val turmeric = new Ingredient("Turmeric", spices)
  val cumin = new Ingredient("Cumin", spices)

  val pairing = new Pairing(turmeric, cumin)
  cumin.addPairing(pairing)

  val session = Neo4jSessionFactory.getNeo4jSession()
  val tx: Transaction = session.beginTransaction()

  try {
    session.save(spices)
    session.save(turmeric)
    session.save(cumin)
    session.save(pairing)
    tx.commit()
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => // tx.rollback()
  } finally {
//    tx.commit()
  }
}
```

The problem is that nothing gets saved to Neo4j. Can you please point out the problem in my code?

Thanks,

Manoj.

Answer (score 2):

Scala’s Long is an instance of a Value class. Value classes were explicitly introduced to avoid allocating runtime objects. At the JVM level therefore Scala's `Long` is equivalent to Java’s primitive `long` which is why it has the primitive type signature  `J`. It cannot be therefore be null, and should not be used as a `graphId`. Although Scala mostly will do auto-boxing between its own `Long` and Java’s `Long` class, this doesn’t apply to declarations, only to operations on those objects.

Comment: Thanks Luanne and Vince. I tried changing Scala's Long to java.lang.Long but it didn't help. I still can't save anything in the DB.

Comment: That's weird because I used your code with java.lang.Long and the graph was persisted

Comment: Thanks for the update Luanne. I've noticed one peculiar thing - if my domain classes derive from Entity, then I am unable to save data in Neo4j, but if I include the id property with the @GraphId annotation directly in those classes, then I am able to save data.

Answer (score 0):

The `@GraphId` isn't being picked up on your entities. I have zero knowledge of Scala but it looks like the scala long isn't liked much by the OGM; `var id: java.lang.Long = _` works fine.